# Unresolved problems: WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new in Automation and automating some code through selenium and Eclipse. i am having this error, i included all external selenium Jars, but don't know how to get rid off this error.

Although i have another project in eclipse which is working fine and automating But unfortunately this Project showing me error.

Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

[Here is the error code Project file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvgu9.png)

[Here is the working Project file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1csx.png)

Comment: You did not import testng in your error project ( you should import webdriver class)

Comment: why should i import TestNG ? if i didnt use it in my project ?

Comment: in your 2 nd project why did not use TestNg once you are using in 1 st project right ?

Comment: beacuse i used some TestNG annotaion in that project thats why i used it.

Comment: @JustinLambert I got a solution by myself. i have to add that selenium External Jars files in **classpath** and  i was adding them in **Modulepath**